# Espresso testing dependencies

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
    defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
// Optional -- Hamcrest library
androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
// Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
// Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
```

I am trying to write the instrumentation test. I am trying to create test class under androidTest/java but it is showing error for all android.test class even I have added all dependencies in gradle.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your build variant you are testing on, Make Sure it is not release.

Change your Gradle file

```
android {
    ...
    testBuildType "debug"
}
```

Now change your current build variant to debug, and then try to compile the project.

For google reference Check below link

https://developer.android.com/studio/test